# Store vim external command result lines into a VimL array, to make a little custom autocomplete

Tags: php, vim, autocomplete

This little snippet aims to make a little autocomplete script in VimL. the first code:

```
cat % | grep function | sed  's/(/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'
```

list all the method inside a php class. For example the output of this command could be:

```
__construct
__toString
foo
bar
```

If I send to complete function an array

```
call complete(col('.'), ["__construct", "__toString", "foo", "bar"])
```

I can see this menu:

[image]

So the final question is, ... how can I transform this:

```
__construct
__toString
foo
bar
```

into this `["__construct", "__toString", "foo", "bar"]`?

Here my wrong code:

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=CustomComplete()<CR>
func! CustomComplete()
    let l:functions = system("cat % | grep function | sed  's/(/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'")
    call complete(col('.'), l:functions)
    return ''
endfunc
```

Comment: just a quick guess, without testing, but just split it by new line should work `split(system("..."), "\n")`

Comment: When I press F5 I se this code `cat: % No such file or directory` pasted in current file

Comment: yeah thats an error in your cat command, see the answer below, it should work. If it doesn't feel free to inform me about the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Refering to the current file

First, the `%` symbol is only parsed in the *command-line*. With `system()`, you need to expand it on your own:

```
system("cat " . expand('%') . " | grep function | sed  's/(/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'")
```

Now, there can be special characters in the current filename. To be safe, wrap the result in `shellescape()`:

```
system("cat " . shellescape(expand('%')) . " | grep function | sed  's/(/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'")
```

#### Turning external command output into a List

You can use the `split()` function with a `{pattern}` of `\n` (newline):

```
let l:functions = split(
\   system("cat " . shellescape(expand('%')) . " | grep function | sed  's/(/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'"),
\   '\n'
\)
```

Recent Vim versions have `systemlist()`, just for this common use case:

```
let l:functions = systemlist("cat " . shellescape(expand('%')) . " | grep function | sed  's/(/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'")
```

Comment: didn't know about systemlist. I still use my custom function for this. Thank you very much. Always appreciate learning new stuff. Will delete my answer, since this one is way better.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: `systemlist()` was introduced in Vim 7.4.256, so it's fairly new; too new for general use by plugins, or if you still have older systems. Your answer would have solved the problem, too; don't let that discourage you!

Comment: no worries i won't. I know my answer worked, but it was written in a hurry, and had far less value to add to stackoverflow. I am rather happy with what I reached in a year in terms of vim (and on SO vim questions). So no need to encourage me, I just wanted to show respect to SO as resources, not as personal achievement, and thank people like you to make it so easy for me to learn a lot about vim/vimscript.